# Rsync Files get Updated over & over

Tags: ubuntu, rsync

Using rsync to update a downloads dir to a backup volume.  A few random (?) files in the source dir get updated every time it runs, despite not having been changed.  What could cause this?

Command line is:

```
rsync -r -t -v --delete -s /path/to/source/* /backup/dir/
```

Both source and dest are on other file systems - source on a server and dest on a USB drive mounted locally.  Everything is on Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: If you replace `-r -t` with `-a`, does that help? In that case, you may have ownerships on some files that aren't transferred since you don't use `-o` or `-g` (which is implied by `-a`). Or, it may have been that the permissions were different on the copy since you did not have `-p` (also included with `-a`).  Also note that `-s` has no effect as the `*` in the source path is expanded by the shell before `rsync` is invoked (`-s` also only affects literal globs on the remote side, and you don't have a remote side here as you're running `rsync` locally).

Comment: No help from switching to -a.  Every dir in the source (whether it has anything new or not) gets echoed to STDOUT in that case.  Quite disruptive.

Comment: What are the two filesystems involved here? Is one of the filesystems a Windows/DOS FS?

Comment: Does that happen _every time_ that you run with `-a`, or just the first time?

Comment: It happens every time now.  Just started a few days ago, not sure why.

Comment: The server-based file system that is my source is ext4, shared through Samba.  The destination USB drive is formatted ntfs.

Comment: Have you looked at [other questions on the site relating to `rsync` and `ntfs`](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=site%3Aunix.stackexchange.com+rsync+ntfs)?

Comment: Yeah - the implication I get from those is, "rsync to NTFS is weird and unpredictable.  Just reformat your target drives."  Not the best plan for me.